# Couldn't identify launch Activity: Default Activity not found (I'm using Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

I can't open the app on my phone because it says it doesn't have a launch activity so I can open it.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.frases.coquinha">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Coquinha">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity
            android:name=".tela2"
            android:exported="false" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not have [a suitable `<intent-filter>` for that on either of your `<activity>` elements](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters).

You need this `<intent-filter>` in whichever of your `<activity>` elements represents your launcher activity:

```xml
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

And, you would need to switch to `android:exported="true"` for that `<activity>` element.